# How do I enter commands in Lubuntu?

Tags: command-line, software-installation, lubuntu

It runs ridiculously slow at times (like 10 minutes to open a browser page) I have not used Linux before and have no idea how to get to a "command prompt" or if that is even where I need to be but would like to try installing metacity as I saw that worked for someone who posted on this forum.

Comment: Before trying to install other things let us know what cpu/ram you have and model of computer.  Terminal should be access by clicking bottom left corner where you open your apps.

Comment: Your release of Lubuntu may also be useful.  Are you using a Lubuntu with LXQt and using GTK+ apps, or a release of Lubuntu using GTK+2 with....    As you provided little info (esp. your RAM size) we can only guess.  The current manual for Lubuntu is at http://manual.lubuntu.me  (assuming 19.04)

Answer (score 1):

To get to a command prompt simultaeously press the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> keys.

Then type `free -h` and tell us how much RAM you have. For example my system shows 8 GB:

```
$ free -h
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           7.7G        5.3G        445M        545M        1.9G        1.4G
Swap:          7.9G        412M        7.5G
```

Copy your four of lines to the clipboard (highlight with mouse and press Ctrl+C). Then edit your question and post the four lines from clipboard (press Ctrl+V) into your question.